# Atom-runner error [Python]

Tags: python, atom-editor, atom-runner

When I try to execute with Atom runner a really simple line of command like this

```
print("Hello World")
```

I have this error:

```
    Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

    ENV PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6\Python 3.6 (64-bit);C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

    Error: spawn python ENOENT
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I have Python 3.6, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using **atom-python-run** package you have to set python executable path,in my case

```
C:\Python3.5\python.exe "{file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Python location is in your path. Just google "changing path"+your OS

---

The PATH variable is kind of like you telling the computer all the places to look if it needs to find something. If it looks in those places and it can't find anything, it gives up. Adding a location to your path is just giving it another location to find things.